# UIImageViews Jump around when a label changes - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uilabel

I have falling UIImageViews falling on the screen and going back to the top in my game. I have another two image views on the bottom of the screen that their images change every so often. When those two bottom images change, the falling UIImageViews jump around the screen to their original position of when the game app opens, then they fall again. The same thing happens when the score label changes.

I have constraints on almost everything so im thinking that might have something to do with it but I don't know why.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

OK so I'm sure you're aware of layout constraints and the `NSLayoutConstraint` class. (If not [read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/)). Basically Apple uses these classes which are represented in the `IB` to position and resize subviews e.t.c.

Because of this you need to adjust the layout constraints of any view you want to move. To animate a UIView it used to be a case of changing the frame property and then getting the superview to redraw it's subviews; however, now you need to change the `constant` property of a view's layout constraints and then call `layoutIfNeeded` on the superview like so:

```
myImageViewConstraint.constant += 100;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    [superview layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Then because you have changed the constraint, the view won't jump around.

Note: you should research this before jumping on Stack Overflow because this is readily available in the [Apple Developer Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html).